# Export Server not configured for Highcharts-export-server

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts

I'm using highcharts-export-server to save images of the charts and attached results when generating PDF. It was working before but now it seems to be broken. I tried to update the node.js and version of npm that I am using and it keeps giving me an error "Export Server not configured." I run node buid.js and install globally the highcharts-expert server but it still gives me the same error.

Package install:
Node - 14.6.0
NPM - 7.6.3
Highcharts-export-server - 2.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I figure out that this issue was caused by wrong input at the step to confirm the CND.

At the CDN step, just press ENTER instead of input `'Y'`. Then all the dependencies will pull from the CDN.

Run the node program, the image will be generated correctly.

[image]

Configure the package by running command line as follows at nodejs project root

```
 node node_modules/highcharts-export-server/build.js
```

Comment: This is the solution which worked for me. Basically, we would need to accept the usage agreement. There are other environment flags mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server), but none actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the highcharts-export-server installed globally (you can do it with the npm list -g -depth 0 highcharts-export-server) and if you have, uninstall it (npm uninstall -g highcharts-export-server). After that, try to run the following command: highcharts-export-server --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --infile ./basic.json --outfile ./chart.png --type png --width 500 and if it fails ('highcharts-export-server' is not recognized), try this one: npx ./node_modules/highcharts-export-server/bin/cli.js --nologo 1 --logLevel 4 --infile ./basic.json --outfile ./chart.png --type png --width 500. Please provide here the final results (attach the generated PNG).

Comment: There's a highcharts-export-server installed globally. I tried re-installing it before but it's giving me the same error. Uninstalling the global highchairs-export-server doesn't fix the issue. Graphs were also not generated when running the codes that you send. I checked the logs and it says that error is on the npm itself. It says '27 error cb() never called!
error This is an error with npm itself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first, export this two environment variable, export ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE=1 and export HIGHCHARTS_VERSION=9.0, them run npm install.